# Indy is sending empty message when i use POST method

Tags: php, delphi, indy

I have to upload a file with my delphi program and handle server side with php

This is my complete code :

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP,
  Vcl.ComCtrls, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,IdSSLOpenSSL;

type
  TForm6 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    od1: TOpenDialog;
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    m1: TMemo;
    IdIOHandlerStack1: TIdIOHandlerStack;
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure HTTPWorkBegin(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;const AWorkCountMax: Integer);
    procedure IdHTTPWork(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;const AWorkCount: Integer);
    procedure IdHTTPWorkEnd(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form6: TForm6;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm6.HTTPWorkBegin(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  const AWorkCountMax: Integer);
begin
   if AWorkMode = wmRead then
   begin
      ProgressBar1.Max := AWorkCountMax;
      ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm6.IdHTTPWork(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  const AWorkCount: Integer);
begin
   if AWorkMode=wmRead then
     ProgressBar1.Position := AWorkCount;
end;


procedure TForm6.IdHTTPWorkEnd(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
end;

procedure TForm6.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Response:string;
   LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  if od1.Execute then
  begin
 //   LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
   // IdHTTP1.IOHandler:=LHandler;
    Response := IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost/delphi/index.php?asd', od1.FileName);
    m1.Text := Response;
  end;
end;

end.
```

The server side is in php:

```
test1
<?php
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

also i changed it to:

```
test1
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

but at the all tests the delphi response is an empty array.

```
test1
Array
(
)
```

Which part of my code is the problem?!

Comment: It depends on how the POST data is encoded. multipart/form-data and proper content boundaries are needed to populate the $_FILES array; or the request has to be form encoded. Try using $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA instead?

Comment: with `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` i got `test1 ÿØÿà`

Comment: Check the value of your Filename and clean the string buffer maybe? Although Delphi shouldn't have buffer contamination problems. Also encode your request. For example "filename=test". The $_POST will show.

Comment: did you checked my code? file will be selected with a open dialog! wich data must be encoded!?

Comment: Yes I follow your code. I'm suggesting that you check the variable value at run time to make sure that the garbled characters aren't introduced during transmission. It's a common debugging technique. Assuming the file you pick is test, is the request URL you use index.php?asdtest, or index.php?asd is the request path, and test is in the POST data? If so, don't send just "test", but write "filename=test" instead

Comment: that url `http://localhost/delphi/index.php?asd` just for test with `$_GET` and it worked with `<?php print_r($_GET);` the data in url only available in php when you use $_GET value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a filename to `TIdHTTP.Post()`.  That posts the raw content of the file as-is.  That will not populate PHP's `$_FILES` array (used for `multipart/form-data` posts) or `$_POST` array (used for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` posts).

Add the file to a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` and post that instead.  It will send a `multipart/form-data` post that should populate the `$_FILES` array, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdMultipartFormData;

procedure TForm6.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  //LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  PostData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  if od1.Execute then
  begin
    //LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    //IdHTTP1.IOHandler := LHandler;

    PostData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      PostData.AddFile('file', od1.FileName);
      m1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost/delphi/index.php?asd', PostData);
    finally
      PostData.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: i got error : `[dcc32 Error] Unit6.pas(40): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TIdMultipartFormDataStream'` which `uses` must added for `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` ?!